# Редактирование текста с числительным

Tags: грамотная-речь

Задание по сдаче мяса ферма, поставившая его, осуществила на 100,3 процентов.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

> Задание по сдаче мяса ферма, поставившая его, *осуществила* **на 100,3**
>   **процентов**

Правильно:

*...выполнила **на 100,3 процента*** (читается: *на сто и **три десятых процента***).

Comment: Лучше бы, конечно, "выполнила", т.е. объединить ваши с Сергеем ответы.

Comment: _Людмила: Лучше бы, конечно, "выполнила"..._ === Согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Задание по сдаче мяса ферма, поставившая его, выполнила на 100,3 процентов.

Или: Ферма выполнила задание по сдаче мяса на 100,3 процентов.

Структура предложения (порядок слов) может зависеть от контекста.